# What plug-in does AirMech require?

Tags: technical-issues, airmech

I recently downloaded [AirMech](http://carbongames.com/), but when I try to run it, [Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/iron)(Chrome) says, "No plug-in available to display this content." What plug-in do I need?

I can confirm that I'm able to view other things using Flash, Java, Unity, HTML5, and Shockwave. I also have the latest version of Iron.

Comment: any chance you are running no script or some other ad blocking mechanism?

Comment: @yx.: It's [Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/iron) so it comes with AdBlock, but I don't use it much, so there's a good chance I'm missing a plug-in.

Comment: hmm... my guess would be flash.  According to [this thread](http://www.srware.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=1567) you can use the same flash plugin that chrome uses.

Comment: @yx.: No, flash works fine.

Comment: You could always apply for the *actual* alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked through an article about it and it suggested you do these three things:

1. Use Chrome. Chromium may have issues with Native Client
2. Type chrome://flags in address bar and enable Override software rendering list (browser restart required)
3. Native Client is enabled in chrome://flags

I may have to take a look at this. Looks like it's built on the Spring engine.

Comment: hmm, nope, didn't work; I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Hm. I don't actually use Chrome, so I can't do any testing on my end.

Comment: Yeah, I asked on their site, and the developer said it only works with Chrome. I tried that and now it works.